# How to create tabbed windows using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

Tabbed windows allow users to drag drop the tab items to rearrange their orders or move them out of the tab bar to turn them to stand-alone windows. They are currently so common. Many apps I'm using have them (e.g. IE, Firefox, Chrome, VS, Android Studio and so on)

I'm looking for a .NET framework or a control library that helps create tabbed windows. I've tried some searches on stackoverflow and Google but there are very few topics about it. One of them bring me to this

http://fabtab.codeplex.com/

Is there nothing from .NET API that can help me with this problem, so I have to create it from the scratch or use a third-party library?

Guys, please give me some suggestions or share me your experience. I can use .NET WinForm or WPF, but if it is an other framework I'll be ready to adopt it.

Comment: [DockPanel Suite](http://dockpanelsuite.com/)

Answer (score 3):

In windows application, you can make two types of applications

1. Multi-form applications
2. Single-form applications

In the multi form application, you have one main form containing child forms and you can display them as docked tabs using tabstrip control.

```
// to add a form in the MdiParent form
     var form = new ChildForm();
    form.MdiParent = this;
    form.Show();
```

In the single form application, the forms are created but not attached to the main form

```
 // to add a form in single form application
    var form = new AnotherForm();
    form.Show(); //  form.ShowDialog() should not be used because it will be modal form
```

in order to achieve what you want, you need to handle drag and drop events for the tabstrip and mainform

if you dragged and dropped a form from outside the main form and dropped it inside, you can easily attach this form to the main form by making `form.MdiParent = this; // this is the main form`

and if you dragged the form from the tabstrip to outside the main form, you dettach the form from the main form

```
from.MdiParent = null;
```

hope this will help you